# Why are there diferent sacrifice offerings for each day of Succot but the same for all days of Pesach?

Tags: passover, korban, sukkot, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, pinchas

For the Pesach sacrifices listed in [Bamidbar 28:16-25](http://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.28.24?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all), we see that the same sacrifice was offered all 7 days of Passover.

When viewing the sacrifices for the 7 days of Succot (I have excluded the 8th day as according to some opinions this is considered its own holiday.) in [Bamidbar 29:12-34](http://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.29?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all) we notice a different offering for each of these days of Succot.

Why is there a difference in these two holidays? Why is specifically Pesach designated to have each day similar and specifically Succot designated to have different sacrifices?

Comment: This is a little exaggerated. The Korbanot of Sukkot follow a very clear pattern and are very very similar to each other.

Comment: I think it may be connected to the international theme of Sukkot...

Comment: based on your comments, i switched from parshanut to taamei hamitvot - switch back if you think original was more appropriate...]

Comment: @Loewian Have to think it over. My reason for placing the *parshanut* tag was obviously motivated by this being in this week's parsha. It may still be appropriate, along with yours, despite the fact that *karbanot* is not a **current** mitzvah. That threw me off for a while until I thought it over.

Comment: I seem to think we have this question already....

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is because the theme of the Pesach offering(s) is the unity of the Jewish people whereas the Sukkot offerings are on behalf of the nations of the world and hence perhaps incorporate a theme of the diversity of the seventy nations (see http://ohr.edu/2349).

Comment: This is a partial answer (unless I missed something). What makes Pesach unique from one idea and Succot for the other?

Comment: @DanF I'm not sure I understand your question - do you mean where do Chazal get that Pesach is about Jewish unity and Sukkot is about the nations of the world? Or what are my references for these ideas?

Comment: @Loewian The first (Where Chaza"l got these ideas?)

Comment: which is why there are 70 bulls offered, one for each of the nations. Apparently 35 of them are nations "ruled" by Yishmael and the other 35 are nations "ruled" by Eisav. Yishmael gets the first, seccond and fourth days (13+12+10) and Eisav the other 4.

Comment: @DanF Well, with regard to the Pesach, you see hints of it in its myriad laws - e.g. about the requirement to identify as a Jew (as opposed to a meshumad), that it was given at the nation's formation, that there's a chiyyuv kares on omitting it, that its bones can't be broken, that families joing together for it, etc. Sukkot, based e.g. on verses in Nach, seems to be related to l'atid lavo when all the nations unite in G-d's service... (See also Shem Mishmuel how had the nation not sinned it would have ben observed as such originally...)